# How to extract XML from a text file

Tags: shell, sed, awk, grep

I have a text file as below.

```
1001=<?xml ns=dkfj><home><taga>dkjf</taga></home>1002=<?xml ns=dkfj><home1><taga>dkjf</taga></home1>
```

I need a result as below.

```
 <?xml ns=dkfj><home><taga>dkjf</taga></home>

 <?xml ns=dkfj><home1><taga>dkjf</taga></home1>
```

I tried with [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed), start and end pattern, but it's not working since both are on the same line.

How can I do it?

Comment: corrected the output format. I have tried sed -n '/<?xml/,/home>/p' filename

Comment: Now I really don't understand what you need. You want each  XML snippet extracted as-is and output on its own line? How do you know where the XML tree ends? Can we assume it is `(\d+=<xml string...>)(\d+=(xml string)*` ?

Comment: Are you sure that's your XML? Because it ... isn't. It looks like XML, but it's invalid. Is that a transposition error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original question would be solved by 
`cat test.xml | tr "<" "\n" | sed -n '/taga>./p' | sed 's/taga>//'`

the second, current question would be solved with
`cat test.xml | sed 's/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]=/\n/g'`

it looks for an occurence of four numbers followed by an = sign, so if you might have those kinds of characters in other places in the real string it wont work, but it doesn't look like that right now

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your snippet, it looks like you've got XML delimited by 'number='. So extract with split:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

local $/;
my @xml_chunks = split ( /\d+\=/, <> );
print Dumper \@xml_chunks;
```

Of course, you should probably note - your XML ... isn't. The declaration isn't valid. I'm going to assume that's a transposition error though. But it *should* be something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

So with your sample data, this will do a reasonable approximation of fixing the XML (assuming of course it isn't valid).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;
use Data::Dumper;

local $/;
my @xml_chunks = split( /\d+\=/, <DATA> );
print Dumper \@xml_chunks;

foreach my $chunk ( grep {/xml/} @xml_chunks ) {
    $chunk =~ s/^<[^>]+>//;
    my $twig = XML::Twig->new( pretty_print => 'indented_a' );
    $twig->parse($chunk);
    $twig->set_encoding('utf-8');
    $twig->set_xml_version('1.0');
    $twig->root->set_att( 'xmlns', 'http://www.some_ns.com' );
    $twig->print;
}
```

Comment: you forgot to comment out your Data::Dumper debugging print.  but +1 anyway for being the only answer to use an XML parser rather than trying to do it with regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I think sed will work, but I'll do a perl solution:

```
 perl -ane 'while (/(<\?xml.*?>)($|\d+=)/g) { push @w,$1; }' \
        -e 'print join("\n",@w)."\n";@w=();'
```

The `/g` regex op in perl says "start the *next* regex match from here in the line". If there is no match, the regex returns 0 (false), ending the `while` loop, allowing the codon to print your output. Meanwhile, matches are accumulated in the array `@w`, which you must clear for the next input line. In the regexp, I'm assuming your search boundary is essentially the digits and equal sign.

Comment: thanks. I have updated the output format. I need the output as per updated one.